# Prevent 'too many connections'(ConnectionPool is not the answer, looking for mysql server side solution)

Tags: mysql, database, connection

A few weeks ago, I post a question about queuing database access request to prevent 'too many connection' error when massive concurrent db requests happen. People told me ConnectionPool is the right way to go which I agreed at that time. However, I finally realized this is not the solution especially when there are a lot of different clients accessing mysql server through network, because connection pool is at client side it can not prevent the sum of connections of all clients from exceeding the max connection number of mysql server.

I think there should be some middleware on the mysql server working as a queue or pool, is anybody familiar with this? Thank you.

I know this question is widely asked, I am also surprised as if there is no total solution for it.

Comment: May be the solution is to write a proxy at the server that create connection pool and pass it to the clients

Comment: I am wondering how these giant network companies use mysql. I know twitter is based on mysql server. I cannot imagine they will properly set connection number of client applications to guarantee the total number is smaller than max connection number of mysql server. This is not a scalable way as you can't spring up more clients promptly, for the sum of client connections may blow up mysql server.

Comment: you talk to twitter by HTTP, not SQL. This means application server, which could balance the load among many MySQL instances. Before that, HTTP itself is balanced among application servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAProxy should perform TCP-level queueing for you purpose. Though, would it be better to build an application server in the middle, to handle incoming flow at more conscious level than TCP. This could require rewriting of both server and clients, but could give you more control over what's happening.

Comment: apart from HAProxy, isn't there some ready middleware for this purpose? I mean dedicated middleware for mysql server, not a general loadbalancer

Comment: what would you expect of this middleware?.. To cache SQL results?.. Your client-server protocol is as low as SQL over TCP, and you are seemingly looking a way around max connections limitaion of MySQL server instance. BTW, you may configure your MySQL instance to handle more connections (buying more RAM, reducing thread footprint).

Comment: Basically I want the middleware to queue access from client in order to avoid 'too many connection' exceptions. I wonder what's the design of the system dealing with millions concurrent accesses?

Comment: this is the field of 'scalable highload web architectures', google for it :) The basic idea is following: you have many boxes, each handling only part of the load. You split the load at many levels, starting from DNS resolving to different IPs for different clients, then you point your clients to different CPU-intensive application servers, which are talking to diffrent memory cache servers, and probably different DB instances. DB instances may be replicated and/or sharded.

Comment: Also, if you are capable of processing 10 requests per second, and you queue another 100 each second, is this right thing to do? :)

Comment: Thanks spacediver. it looks like the only way is to build a mysql server farm for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is actually a pretty complicated problem.

First of all you need to decide whether mis-alignments in data are acceptable, for example: if you store in the database the number of Likes received, and you ask this number at 12:00:00, and the number in the DB is 500, and someone posts a LIKE at 12:00:01, and you query it again at 12:00:02; is it OK to receive "500" again, even if the correct number should be 501, provided that in a little time the answer "501" does come out?

If this is acceptable (the infamous "301 bug" in YouTube), then you might start caching some SELECT responses.

You might even cache them in middleware, i.e. have a special process running continuously and hogging ONE connection to MySQL, and answering requests in a queue. You might run it internally in the server as a Web server on port 8001 and have an Apache ReverseProxy, HAproxy, pound, or NginX location to proxy it outside.

You can do the same for special UPDATE/DELETE queries even if it's trickier.

It would be best to cache queries running asynchronously through AJAX first, if any, because serializing queries with a proxy is liable to perceptibly slow down the application.

You have a threefold target:

- run queries on MySQL as fast as possible (look into indexing and MySQL caching) in order to free the ConnectionPool and keep it as lightly loaded as possible.
- refactor the application in order to extract all information from queries (e.g., the number of rows with a certain property AND those rows as data are often retrieved using TWO queries, but with proper management you need only one and a SQLNumRows() call. Also, quite often similar queries with different informations are run, when a single query might have returned all information at one go: typically, one query to check user/password, another to fetch the complete user profile).
- divert the most calls possible to something not at all (NginX, middleware) or lightly (queuing process) bound to MySQL; in the latter case, using a known number of connections in order to run predictably.

Unfortunately there's no easy "magic bullet" to solve this problem (except of course increasing the number of connections, maybe replicating the DB on several hosts running as master-slave. While not really a magic bullet, it is easier to design and implement).

Comment: thanks for reply. To reduce the mysql queries, I am considering to use lucene to cache select result.